# UIPageViewController: image under dots

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Please tell me how can i shove images under dots?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466718/can-we-customize-the-page-indicator-in-uipageviewcontroller) has a similar issue & solution.

In short: the standard UIPageControl object doesn't allow much customisation.