# UIPageViewController get current number page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I need to show the current number of View how can i do this??

I think this method is usual, because notifies me when an animation ends

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
       didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished 
  previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers 
      transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{

}
```

Comment: [visit]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466718/can-we-customize-the-page-indicator-in-uipageviewcontroller

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController: return the current visible view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view)